# hosting C# windows service or alternative to run continuous tasks in shared hosting environment

Tags: windows-services, hosting, shared-hosting

My application required to run continuous tasks without any user intervention but I am finding difficult how to host it on shared virtual server as a windows service, because those control panels are only providing access to IIS.

My questions is what will be way to achieve this goal or alternative to run continuous task on shared hosted server?

I am not thinking for dedicated server because that is too costly..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you define "continuous" in your case?
Since you can't get access to a physical box (or even full access to a virtual box), your options are kind of limited.

You could have an ASP.NET application that is kept alive somehow (most shared hosting environment will recycle when there aren't requests, but there are ways around that) that runs a process on a timer in the background. We've done this with some cleanup tasks for sites before.

But if you need something more continuous than that... I don't know. I think you're either going to need to get full access to a box so you can install your service, or change the idea of how your service runs.

Comment: in my case i have to fetch data periodically, process it (better within c#) and then update the tables or views back